# find resolution and fps with ffprobe or ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file

I have a bunch of mkv files in a folder and would like to find the resolution and fps of all the files and write this to a text file.

I've found each command for finding resolution and fps below, but how do I combine these and loop through the directory and write the results to a text file?

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width -of csv=s=x:p=0 filename.mkv



ffprobe -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams 0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate filename.mkv
```

Comment: `for %f in (*.mkv) do (` ... one or more commands using `"%f"` ... `)` (Of course, in a batch script you must use `%%f` instead of `%f`.) See `for /?` for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cycle through the files in a directory, use a `For` loop, *enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt for its usage information*.

In the following example, because I've asked for all the information in just one call to `ffprobe`, and used `x` as the separator, *(`s=x`)*, I've ran the output through a `For /F` loop to better separate the two pieces of information required:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "C:\MyFolder\*.mkv" ((For %%A In (
    "C:\MyFolder\*.mkv") Do For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=x" %%B In ('
    "ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate,height,width -of csv=s=x:p=0 "%%A""
') Do Echo "%%~nxA", %%Bx%%C, %%D))>"stream_entries.log"
Pause
Exit /B
```

*Change both instances of `C:\MyFolder\`, (lines `2` and `3`), and the name of the output file, (`stream_entries.log`), which will be saved to the current directory, as necessary.*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I've modified the script a bit but it still works great. Is there a way to output the resolution as eg. 2k or 4k and fps as 30 or 60 instead of 3840x2160 and 30000/1001?

```
@Echo Off
If Exist "*.mkv" ((For %%A In (
    "*.mkv") Do For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=x" %%B In ('
    "ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate,height,width -of csv=s=x:p=0 "%%A""
') Do Echo %%Bx%%C, %%D,    %%~nxA))> "%~n0.log"
Exit /B
```